# How does ft-c-omni work and how can I make it faster?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-c, ins-completion

As I was studying the various ways of doing completion in Vim 8.0, I came across the very interesting "omni-completion" feature and its `'omnifunc'` option, which is specialized as `ccomplete#Complete` for the C `filetype` (`:h ft-c-omni`).

I tried it out on a "Hello, World!" example and I was pleased by the promising results so I decided to put it to the test by trying to complete the field of a structure somewhere in the Linux Kernel (after having run `make tags`). On a fairly decent laptop, this took over a minute, which is slightly problematic for anyone with a speed of typing above 1 WPM.

So how is that feature implemented and is there an undocumented way of making it go faster (pre-computing, caching, ...) so that it can be usable in large projects such as the Kernel? Or is `ft-c-omni` effectively useless for such real-world use-cases?

Comment: Re-writing the omni completion function in Vim9 script could help.  The functions would be compiled which could increase the execution speed by a factor somewhere between 10 and 100.  I started a refactoring: [see here](https://0x0.st/ivkX.txt) for the code.  You'll need a very recent Vim version (it works on 8.2.1250).  To try the code, write it into `~/.vim/autoload/ccomplete.vim`. Out of the 10 functions, I was able to refactor only 2 functions. If you notice some speed improvement, I may try to refactor the remaining 8.

Answer (score 2):

> So how  is that  feature implemented  and is there  an undocumented  way of
> making it go faster (pre-computing, caching,  ...) so that it can be usable
> in large projects  such as the Kernel? Or is  ft-c-omni effectively useless
> for such real-world use-cases?

The C omni completion function is implemented in [`$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/ccomplete.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim).

I profiled it with a very simple test:

```
$ vim -S <(cat <<'EOF'
    cd ~/Vcs/vim
    e src/evalfunc.c
    prof start /tmp/profile.log
    prof func ccomplete#Complete
    so $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/ccomplete.vim
    au VimEnter * call feedkeys("Oe\<c-x>\<c-o>", 'xt') | qa!
EOF
)
```

Here are [the results](https://0x0.st/iYD9.txt).

Your environment is different, so you probably want to profile the function on your machine.  Here's how:

- run `:prof start /tmp/profile.log` to tell Vim you want to profile "something", and that the results should be written inside `/tmp/profile.log`
- run `:so $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/ccomplete.vim` to tell Vim to source the script where the `ccomplete#Complete()` function is defined
- run `:prof func ccomplete#Complete` to tell Vim that the "something" you want to profile is the function `ccomplete#Complete()`

Now, all you have to do is to call the function at least once (i.e. press `C-x C-o` after some text inside a file of your project), then quit Vim.  See [`:h profiling`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#profile).

On my machine, the function spends little time in executing code of its own; most of the time is spent in code run by nested function calls:

```
FUNCTIONS SORTED ON TOTAL TIME
count  total (s)   self (s)  function
    2   0.775950   0.065477  ccomplete#Complete()
                   ^------^
                   only 8% of the total time is spent for its own code
```

Now you need to find out which nested function calls take the most time; on my machine there are two:

```
1   0.245847   0.006270     call extend(res, map(tags, 's:Tag2item(v:val)'))
1   0.476847   0.005951   return map(res, 's:Tagline2item(v:val, brackets)')
│   │          │
│   │          └ but it took only that much time for the command itself
│   └ it took that much time in total
└ the command has been executed only once
```

They call [`s:Tag2item()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L194) and [`s:Tagline2item()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L244).  I've profiled `s:Tagline2item()` which is the slowest of them: here are [the results](https://0x0.st/iYDf.txt).

Again, you probably want to profile the function on your machine.  The procedure is exactly the same as before; with one exception; you can't run this:

```
:prof func s:Tagline2item
           ^^
           ✘
```

You must translate `s:` into a sequence such as `<SNR>123_`.

```
:prof func <SNR>123_Tagline2item
           ^-------^
               ✔
```

Where `123` is the id of the script where `s:Tagline2item()` is defined.  You can get it by running `:scriptnames`, or you can type this on the command-line:

```
:func s:Tagline2item
```

Then:

- press `Tab` to make Vim translate `s:`
- press `C-b` to jump at the start of the command-line
- insert `prof`
- press `Enter` to run the command

On my machine, `s:Tagline2item()` spends little time in executing code of its own; most of the time is spent in code run by nested function calls:

```
FUNCTIONS SORTED ON TOTAL TIME
count  total (s)   self (s)  function
 1036   0.483790   0.057566  <SNR>178_Tagline2item()
                   ^------^
                   only 12% of the total time is spent for its own code
```

Again, you need to find out which command(s) take(s) the most time; on my machine [it's this one](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L344):

```
1036   0.436545   0.010321   let add = s:GetAddition(line, a:val['match'], [a:val], a:brackets == '')
```

It calls `s:GetAddition()` (here is its [profile](https://0x0.st/iYDy.txt)), which is slow mainly because of [this command](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L254):

```
757   0.401642   0.007140   if len(s:SearchMembers(a:memarg, [''], 0)) > 0
```

It calls `s:SearchMembers()` (here is its [profile](https://0x0.st/iYDw.txt)), which is slow mainly because of [this command](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L625):

```
33   0.299922   0.000560      call extend(res, s:Nextitem(strpart(line, s, e - s), a:items, 0, a:all))
```

It calls `s:Nextitem()` (here is its [profile](https://0x0.st/iYDt.txt)), which is slow mainly because of [this command](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f39397e515067d5a314be99778e63fe0acf93c51/runtime/autoload/ccomplete.vim#L432):

```
33              0.281755     let diclist = taglist('^' . tokens[tidx] . '$')
```

This command alone takes more than a third of the total time used by `C-x C-o`.

To make it faster you could try to cache the output of `taglist()`, and only invoke it if the necessary information can't be found in the cache.

I didn't profile every function to find all the slowest commands, but there are probably a few others that you could refactor to make the omni completion faster.  If you go that route, don't perform your experiments directly in `$VIMRUNTIME`; do them in your `~/.vim`.  Write your autoload script in `~/.vim/autoload/ccomplete.vim`:

```
:e ~/.vim/autoload/ccomplete.vim
:r $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/ccomplete.vim
```

Since `~/.vim` comes before `$VIMRUNTIME` in the runtimepath, when `C-x C-o` will invoke `ccomplete#Complete()`, your definition will be found first; the other one will be ignored.

---

You could also try to refactor the code in Vim9 script.  See here for [an example](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7497).

It works on 8.2.2332.  With this implementation, the commands won't be parsed every time you press `C-x C-o`; they will be compiled into instructions which can be executed more efficiently.  You can read them by executing:

```
:pu=execute('disassemble ccomplete#Complete')
```

It should write a long list of instructions, such as:

```
ccomplete#Complete
    if findstart
   0 LOAD arg[-2]
   1 JUMP_IF_FALSE -> 146


        let line = getline('.')
   2 PUSHS "."
   3 BCALL getline(argc 1)
   4 STORE $0


        let start = col('.') - 1
   5 PUSHS "."
   6 BCALL col(argc 1)
   7 PUSHNR 1
   8 OPNR -
   9 STORE $1
   ...
```

Note that since `ccomplete#Complete()` is autloaded, and `:disassemble` only works on installed functions, you must have pressed `C-x C-o` at least once.

I doubt it will help that much, because the main bottleneck is probably not Vim script here, but it's worth a try.