# How often and when is foldexpr evaluated?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, cursor-movement, folding

I want to toggle `foldmethod` between `expr` and `manual` because if we always set `foldmethod=expr`, then the cursor tends to move slowly in vim.

I think that `foldexpr` is evaluated just after switching `foldmethod=expr`, thus I try to toggle at every 5000ms in the following way.
However, `foldexpr` can't be evaluated, which implies `foldexpr` is not evaluated just after switching `foldmethod=expr`.

Then, I have a question: how often or when is `foldexpr` evaluated?
To my knowledge, there does not exist any document about timing of evaluation of `foldexpr`.

```
function! s:enable_expr(timer_id) abort
  setlocal foldmethod=expr
  setlocal foldmethod=manual
endfunction
autocmd CursorMoved * call s:cursor_moved()

let s:timer_id = timer_start(5000, function('s:enable_expr'))

function! s:cursor_moved() abort
  setlocal foldmethod=manual

  call timer_stop(s:timer_id)
  let s:timer_id = timer_start(5000, function('s:enable_expr'))
endfunction
```

**REMARK**:
I know a way to toggle them by using `InsertEnter` and `InsertLeave` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280457/stop-vim-from-dynamically-updating-folds).
But, if we employ the toggle in this way, then switching between insert mode and normal mode can become slow.
Moreover, I use the command `<C-o>` a lot in insert mode, thus we want to avoid this implementation.

Thus, I want to make vim evaluate `foldexpr` once in all lines when the cursor holds.

**Additional REMARK**:
I toggle them with the following implementation for now.
A drawback of this implementation is when we move the cursor after 5000ms under the cursor-hold, the move of the cursor becomes slowly at the beginning due to the switching `foldmethod`.

```
function! s:enable_expr(timer_id) abort
  if &l:foldmethod ==# 'manual'
    setlocal foldmethod=expr
  endif
endfunction
autocmd CursorMoved * call s:cursor_moved()

let s:timer_id = timer_start(5000, function('s:enable_expr'))

function! s:cursor_moved() abort
  if &l:foldmethod ==# 'expr'
    setlocal foldmethod=manual
  endif
  call timer_stop(s:timer_id)
  let s:timer_id = timer_start(5000, function('s:enable_expr'))
endfunction
```

**A temporary solution**

```
augroup foldmethod-syntax
  autocmd InsertEnter,CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * if &l:foldmethod ==# 'expr'
  \                   |   setlocal foldmethod=manual
  \                   | endif
  autocmd BufWrite * if &l:foldmethod ==# 'manual'
  \                   |   setlocal foldmethod=expr
  \                   | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Another option would be to toggle foldenable on and off

Comment: Thank you! I know a way to toggle them by using `InsertEnter` and `InsertLeave`. However, if we toggle them in this way, then the command `<C-o>` in insert mode tends to be slowly due to the toggle. I want to avoid this situation.

Comment: Try to profile your folding expression.  See [:h profile](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#profile), and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26880/17449).  Rewriting the expression inside a `:def` function might increase the performance; once fixed, [this todo item](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/997cd1a17f030d004b334d17cf1c1c57050c9906/runtime/doc/todo.txt#L143-L145) might help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look into vim source code:

There is a function which is called when a change was made:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/85629985b71035608a37ba3bde86968481490d46/src/change.c#L429

This function triggers `foldUpdate`:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/85629985b71035608a37ba3bde86968481490d46/src/change.c#L537

Which does folding (including foldexpr):

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/81fcb67fb32a12414512b72e691a1bbbff9f8511/src/fold.c#L842

This also happens when you start editing a file:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/451c2e3536a3cb77d07faf3cb2b834512e174351/src/ex_cmds.c#L1270

And when you set `foldexpr` options:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d43906d2e5969288f239df851f5ad7b1dc2c7251/src/optionstr.c#L1994

And so on.

**PS**

There is a plugin https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold that probably does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Your proposal plugin is just what I want!!